# Cairo RGB color range

Tags: haskell, colors, cairo

I'm using cairo in haskell, and the setSourceRGB function takes values between 0 and 1. Does anyone know how this corresponds to the standard 0-255 gradient? As in, is the 255 gradient evenly distributed over 0-1, or is it somehow different?

Comment: That is certainly the usual practice in such libraries. — Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 4):

From the [colour](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/colour-2.3.3/docs/Data-Colour.html#g:1) package documentation, whose author definitely knows more about colours than you or I:

> Interfacing with the colour for other libraries, such as cairo and OpenGL, can be a challenge because these libraries often do not use colour spaces in a consistent way. The problem is that these libraries work in a device dependent colour space and give no indication what the colour space is. For most devices this colours space is implicitly the non-linear sRGB space. However, to make matters worse, these libraries also do their compositing and blending in the device colour space. Blending and compositing ought to be done in a linear colour space, but since the device space is typically non-linear sRGB, these libraries typically produce colour blends that are too dark.
>
> Because these other colour libraries can only blend in device colour spaces, they are fundamentally broken and there is no "right" way to interface with them.